# Powershell script to copy selected substring from a line of string

Tags: powershell

How to get the test name from the below line using powershell script?

```
<UnitTestResult executionId="200af923-6299-5624-0558-933a879a4851" testId="0908f758-64a1-ad61-6b63-9acfda6ddf9c" testName="atmentRelatedInformationComponent setTreatmentRowItem: should not set the report Id  to the IReport model if report id is missing or isReportAvailable" computerName="INBLRH11651WSPR" duration="00:00:00.011" startTime="2021-06-15T17:50:00.642Z" endTime="2021-06-15T17:50:00.642Z" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Passed" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d"/>
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Answer (score 2):

The input string is technically a complete XML document, so you could do:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<UnitTestResult executionId="200af923-6299-5624-0558-933a879a4851" testId="0908f758-64a1-ad61-6b63-9acfda6ddf9c" testName="atmentRelatedInformationComponent setTreatmentRowItem: should not set the report Id  to the IReport model if report id is missing or isReportAvailable" computerName="INBLRH11651WSPR" duration="00:00:00.011" startTime="2021-06-15T17:50:00.642Z" endTime="2021-06-15T17:50:00.642Z" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Passed" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d"/>
'@

# This will result in the test name
$xml.UnitTestResult.testName
```

Comment: @AvinVerma Then do it once for each line.

Comment: This line is a part of one trx file, there is  multiple lines like  that in the file.

Comment: Is there any way to get test name without converting it into xml